# Redirect to a server after login

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, url-rewriting, http-redirect, response.redirect

I have a VM with IIS server and one self hosting server. The self hosting server is accessible only inside the VM. 
In IIS I set up a website which is accessible outside the VM, A .net MVC app is hosted on the IIS website and once successfull login user should redirect to the self hosting server. 
Now using the below code it is redirecting to the internal server inside the VM(IE inside the VM). 
But when trying to access from outside the VM - It says this site can.t be reached after successful login.
Could anyone help me what I am missing here.

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return Redirect("http://selfhostingserver.com");
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide the bindings of both IIS sites?

Comment: The self hosting server is hosted on localhost 8030, and iis is running on default 8080 port